# MongoDB updating wrong subdocument in an array

Tags: mongodb

my gamefamilies collection looks like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('54cc3ee7894ae60c1c9d6c74'),
    "game_ref_id": "REF123",
    ..
    "yearwise_details": [
    {
        "year": 1,
        ...
        "other_details": [
            {
                "type": "cash",
                "openingstock": 988
                ..
            },
            {
                "type": "FLU",
                "openingstock": 555
                ..
            },
            ..other items
        ]
    },
    {
        "year": 2,
        ...

        "other_details": [
            {
                "type": "cash",
                "openingstock": 3000,
                ....
            },
            ...
            {
                "type": "ghee",
                "openingstock": 3000,
                ...
            },
            ..
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My update query

> db.gamefamilies.update({"game_ref_id": "REF123", "teamname": "manisha","yearwise_details.year": 2, "yearwise_details.other_details.type": "ghee"}, {"$set": {"yearwise_details.0.other_details.$.openingstock": 555} });

Document is getting picked up correctly. I expect to update year 2's item type="ghee" but instead year 1's 2nd item (type FLU) gets updated. What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

regards
Manisha

Comment: try to make {yearwise_details.1.other_details.$.openingstock": 555}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not yet support for nested [$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update) updates.

So you can hardcode the update with

```
db.gamefamilies.update({"game_ref_id": "REF123",
                        "teamname": "manisha",
                        "yearwise_details.year": 2,
                        "yearwise_details.other_details.type": "ghee"},
                       {"$set":
                         {"yearwise_details.1.other_details.$.openingstock": 555}});
```

But notice that the **`yearwise_details.1.other_details`** is hardcoding that you want the second value of the array (it is 0-indexed, so the `1` is referencing the second element). I am assuming you found the command you have in your question because it worked for the first element of the array. But it will only ever work on the first element and the command above will only ever work on the second element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I get index of yearwise_details ? Also I believe if I make 'yearwise_details' as an object (instead of an array) then that might solve my issue as well.  If I make it an object can I add new 'yearwise_details' - i.e. new year sub document easily  ?

Comment: The only way to get the index of the `yearwise_details` that you are searching for, you would need to use the `$` the way that you are using it for the `other_details` details array. Is it possible to change the `other_details` array from being an array of objects with a `type` field value of `cash` or `ghee` to being an object with `cash` as the field for the rest of the `cash` object and `ghee` being the field for the rest of the `field` object instead of specifying the type within the subdocument? Otherwise, you could turn `yearwise_details` into an object from an array, but it loses order.

Comment: And it would be a little more difficult. Instead of `push`ing the objects, you would have to `$set` the subdocument field with the value of the object you would have pushed.

Comment: Is it something like below you are saying:  
    {  "_id": ObjectId('54cc3ee7894ae60c1c9d6c74'),
 "game_ref_id": "REF123",
 ..
 "yearwise_details": [
  {
   "year": 1,
   ...
   cash: {
    "openingstock": 988
     ..
    },
   ghee:{
    "openingstock": 555
     ..
   },
   ..
  },
  {
   "year": 2,
   ...  
   cash: {
    "openingstock": 3000,
    ....
   },
   ...
   ghee: {
    "openingstock": 3000,
    ...
   },
   ..
   
  }
 ]
}

Comment: yes that's very much possible. With this structure I will try all my queries again. What I observed is even I need to hard code index for other_details like yearwise_details.1.other_details.15